# Array index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, title

I have successfully build a search function which searches and displays the TableView title and and subtitle in a detailviewcontroller. In the detailviewcontroller there's two text labels, one for the title and one for the subtitle.

Displaying the title and subtitles in the cells works fine, including tapping and seeing them in the detailviewcontroller. But when typing in the search function the app crashes due to:

> fatal error: Array index out of range
>   (lldb)
>
> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here's all my code:

```
 let quotes = [
   "Saying1",
   "Saying2",]//End

let persons = [
    "Name1",
    "Name2",

]//End 

var filteredQuotes = [String]()
var filteredPersons = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        self.tableView.reloadData()


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
        return self.filteredQuotes.count
    }
    else
    {
        return self.quotes.count
         }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
        cell!.textLabel?.text = self.filteredQuotes[indexPath.row]
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filteredPersons[indexPath.row] //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
    }
    else
    {
        cell!.textLabel?.text = self.quotes[indexPath.row]
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.persons[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell!
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SearchDetailViewController {

            let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)
            destination.viaSegue = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!
            destination.viaSeguePerson =(cell?.detailTextLabel?.text!)!
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    _ = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    if let _ = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self)
    }

}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredQuotes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    self.filteredPersons.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let Quotesarray = (self.quotes as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    self.filteredQuotes = Quotesarray as! [String]

    let Personsarray = (self.persons as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    self.filteredPersons = Personsarray as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Post the complete crash log and tag your question correctly (remove `xcode` and add `swift`).

Comment: Does `filteredPersons` contain the data you think it contains? Have you logged the contents? Why are you storing data in 2 separate arrays? It looks to me like a quote belongs to a person right? Why not make an object called `Quote` that contains a String for the quote and a String for the name? Then you only need one array called `quotes` or something.

Comment: What assures you that `Quotesarray` and `Personsarray` contains the same amount (and the corresponding ones by the way) data? Ex: Quotes with @"I think; therefore I am", and so Persons with "René Descartes", and you search "Descartes", what should `Quotesarray` and `Personsarray` have?

Comment: Can you share your code in Github please, I think I know what's your problem but I need to see your full code first

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you, the complete crash log is (<UISearchController: 0x7fca00ea9760>)
fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)

Comment: @Fogmeister That sounds like a great solution, to only have one array instead of two! You're totally right, they belong together. Would you please show me how to do so? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Larme There's the same amount in both the arrays and they have corresponded together every time. But a solution with only one array must be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @Larme and @Fogmeister suggest, you can improve this with a structured array - here's an example of how you might do that part.

define a struct to hold your data like this

```
struct Quotes
{
    var person : String
    var quote  : String
}
```

and the initialise it like this

```
let quotes = [Quotes(person: "name 1", quote: "saying 1"),
               Quotes(person: "name 2", quote: "saying 2")  ]
```

alternatively, of course, you could initialise an empty array, and then append data as you retrieve it from somewhere - database, or user input

```
var quotes : [Quotes] = []

let quote1 = Quotes(person: "name 3", quote: "saying 3")        
quotes.append(quote1)
```

or

```
quotes.append(Quotes(person: "name 4", quote: "saying 4"))
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do I then implement the new array in the other parts of the code? (dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and updateSearchResultsForSearchController functions for example)? I mean so that everything works together? Really appreciate your help guys @Russell

Comment: just exactly the same as you already are - but instead of working with two arrays, you have a single array with attributes - so quotes[index].person and quotes[index].quote, rather than person[index] and quote[index]

Comment: I'm getting an error in the updateSearchResultsForSearchController regarding the let Quotesarray = (self.quotes as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate) line. It says " Cannont convert value of type '[SearchTableViewController.Quotes]' to type 'NSArray' in coercion"  I apologise for my inexperience, thank you once again.

Comment: there are good example of how to fix this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276848/swift-filtering-an-array-of-structures-using-uisearchcontroller-predicates 

the problem is that self.quotes is not a simple array, it's an custom array of a struct, but have a look at the earlier answer

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out, I have tried to implement the example you linked but now the search function isn't working at all - nothing shows up when I search. :(

Comment: Found it ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030171/cannot-convert-value-of-type-record-to-type-record-in-coercion