# How to implement search using array of custom objects with help of NSPredicate?

Tags: swift, swift3, nspredicate

```
private  var contactsWithSections = [[WPH]]()
```

WPH have following properties:

```
class WPH: NSObject {
    var fName: String? = nil
    var lName: String? = nil
    var number: String? = nil
    var email: String? = nil
}
```

I want to search based on fName i.e. in array have fname = alex, fname = alena, fname = flora

```
let searchStr = "al"
```

Then result should return objects for alex and alena

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Filtering an array of structures using UISearchController/Predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276848/swift-filtering-an-array-of-structures-using-uisearchcontroller-predicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the more relevant solution that is a perfect match for my problem

```
let filtered = MasterList!.filter { (data) -> Bool in
            return data.fName?.range(of: Key, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) != nil || data.lName?.range(of: Key, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) != nil
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use flat map  then Filter

FlatMap will join all section filter will filter it with your key

```
let results  =  contactsWithSections.flatMap {$0}.filter { (obj) -> Bool in
        guard let keyValue = obj.fName else  {return false}
        return keyValue == searchStr
    }
```

Comment: it will not work for me. 

private  var contactsWithSections = [[WPH]]()

if have sections and contents. 

I need to search all matches with 
let searchStr = "al" but your code will returns unique values.

Comment: flat map is working fine but not returning matched results.

Comment: this previous code should return matched result if condition ok , you will apply flatmap and after that will apply filter on flatted array see solution